# I created a linegraph using UIBezierPath .for every minute the data is going change in linegraph so i need to animate last line of line graph

Tags: ios

```
CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];

pathAnimation.duration = 2.0;
pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
pathAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];

[pathLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
```

Instead of the path, how can I set animation to last line ?

Comment: What do you mean by "last line"? If you want to animate only the last 10th of the path, you could do `pathAnimation.fromValue = @(0.9);` (and, of course, you could use this `NSNumber` literal syntax for the end, too, e.g. `pathAnimation.fromValue = @(1.0);`.

Comment: i did that  ,but not working .How can i set animation from  that point

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "set animation to last line" and or "animate only one line in that path"?

Comment: And what does your code result in? What do you want it to do? Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: i want  to animate one line  in that path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just animate "the last line in a path". But you can achieve the visual effect by using two entirely separate shape layers, one with the path thus far that is not to be animated (the blue path in my example below) and a completely separate layer whose path is just the last the segment of the line, which will be animated (a red path in my example). You can then:

- Make the path of the blue shape layer to be the just the existing, unanimated portion of the final path.
- Make the path for the red shape layer to be just the last segment of the new path;
- Animate the red layer's `strokeEnd` from `@(0.0)` to `@(1.0)`;
- When that's done (e.g. in `animationDidStop:finished:`), remove that red shape layer's path altogether and extend the path of the blue shape layer's path; and
- Repeat as needed.

When you do this, it will look like you animated another segment onto the blue shape layer, but what you really did is that you create a separate layer with just the portion to be animated, animate that, and when done, remove that layer and update the original layer's path accordingly

[image]

Note, in the above animated example, the red path and the blue paths are on different shape layers, but it almost feels like it's one path because one layer's path starts right where the other one left off. Clearly, in your final product, you would make the two shape layers appear the same, which would be less jarring than the red/blue combination above. I just used different colors here so you could understand what the two different shape layers were doing.

FYI, this is the code that generated the above drawing:

```
- (void)addLineToPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    // create a path that consists just of the portion to be animated

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:self.lastPoint];
    [path addLineToPoint:point];

    // set the redAnimatedPathLayer's path to be this short segment

    self.redAnimatedPathLayer.path = [path CGPath];

    // and animate it

    CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    self.redAnimatedPathLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    pathAnimation.duration = 0.5;
    pathAnimation.fromValue = @(0.0);
    pathAnimation.toValue = @(1.0);
    pathAnimation.delegate = self;
    [self.redAnimatedPathLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEndKey"];

    // save the point for future reference

    self.lastPoint = point;
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
    // update the blue layer's path to include this new point

    [self.mainPath addLineToPoint:self.lastPoint];
    self.blueNonAnimatedLayer.path = self.mainPath.CGPath;

    // reset the red layer's path

    self.redAnimatedPathLayer.path = nil;

    [self repeat];
}
```